# Time comparison in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but I could not make time filtering to work.

Here is my sample query:

```sql
select toTimeZone(ts, 'Etc/GMT+2') as z
from (select toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:35:00') AS ts)
where z > '2019-08-31 20:34:00'
```

I would expect 0 results, but getting:

```
2019-08-31T18:35:00+00:00
```

Is it a bug, or do I misuse the toTimeZone() function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ClickHouse stores DateTime as Unix timestamp - other words without timezone. 
But timezone is taken into account when sql-query executed:

```sql
SELECT
    toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:35:00', 'UTC') AS origin_date,

    toTimeZone(origin_date, 'Etc/GMT+2') AS d1,
    toTypeName(d1) AS type1,
    toUnixTimestamp(d1) AS t1,

    toTimeZone(origin_date, 'UTC') AS d2,
    toTypeName(d2) AS type2,
    toUnixTimestamp(d2) AS t2
FORMAT Vertical

Row 1:
──────
origin_date: 2019-08-31 20:35:00

d1:          2019-08-31 18:35:00
type1:       DateTime('Etc/GMT+2')
t1:          1567283700 # <-- t1 == t2

d2:          2019-08-31 20:35:00
type2:       DateTime('UTC')
t2:          1567283700 # <-- t1 == t2
```

Your query works correctly.

To 'reset the timezone' of *z*-date can be used this way:

```sql
SELECT toDateTime(toString(toTimeZone(ts, 'Etc/GMT+2'))) AS z
FROM
(
    SELECT toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:35:00') AS ts
)
WHERE z > '2019-08-31 20:34:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir. Makes sense. Then it's weird that grouping by toStartOfInterval(ts, $interval, $timeZone) works as I initially expected. If under the hood grouping happens on the unix timestamp, I would have expected that timezone param is ignored. Or does it group on the resulting string. That way or another I see inconsistencies, but I guess I'm not the first one who is puzzled by that (https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/5206)

Answer (score 1):

TZ is a property of the type not of the value

```
DESCRIBE TABLE
(
    SELECT
        toTimeZone(toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:35:00'), 'Etc/GMT+2') AS x,
        toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:35:00') AS y
)

┌─name─┬─type──────────────────┬─
│ x    │ DateTime('Etc/GMT+2') │
│ y    │ DateTime              │
└──────┴───────────────────────┴─


SELECT toTimeZone(ts, 'Etc/GMT+2') AS z
FROM
(
    SELECT toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:35:00') AS ts
)
WHERE z > toDateTime('2019-08-31 20:34:00', 'Etc/GMT+2')

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Comment: Hi Denis, is there any description how that type value exactly affects the query result? Or is it some sort of hidden knowledge?